# Android error "/dev/block/dm-15: can't write sector"

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I'm getting the above error repeatedly in my logcat - and it seems to be preventing me from launching my app onto the device.

[image: the problem]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your nand seems faulty. Log into `adb shell` and type `dmesg` you will see that the kernel complains that the hardware is defective.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I fixed this by deleting the \system\bin\toolbox file from my device, as this is supposedly only for emulators. Still can't boot my app onto the device though :/

Comment: NO. Toolboox is not only for emulators, it is needed for the device to work. IMHO - you bricked your device.